# How to add cache for a site?

Tags: html, caching

Based on [Google page speed tool](http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com/), I should leverage browser caching. How do I do that for [my site](http://bfcards.edicypages.com/list-of-cards/abyssal-warder-fire)? I just need to cache all assets excluding the static HTML page. What codes do I add? And where do I add these code in the html page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to have the browser cache the static elements (typically: CSS, JS, images), you must send the required HTTP headers for those elements.

Note that it has nothing to do with your HTML page : CSS/JS/images are fetched using distinct HTTP request -- one per asset.

What you need to do is configure your Webserver, so it send HTTP headers to indicate the browser it should cache those items.

Typically, if using Apache, you'll work with [**`mod_expires`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html), and you'll use some configuration block like this one :

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive   On
    ExpiresByType   text/css    "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType   application/javascript    "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType   image/gif    "access plus 1 weeks"
    ExpiresByType   image/png    "access plus 1 weeks"
    ExpiresByType   image/jpeg    "access plus 1 weeks"
</IfModule>
```

Note: you'll probably want to change the caching durations, to fit your needs.

Comment: Awww, it has nothing to do with html? I don't have access to the server, my site is hosted by someone else.

Comment: The HTML page is one thing ; each JS/CSS/image is another thing, independent of the HTML page -- each time, you have a distinct HTTP request.

Comment: You might still be able to write a .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think edicy.com doesn't allow writing of .htaccess file

Comment: You're welcome :-) Well, too bad if you cannot enable things like caching (mod_expires) and compression (mod_deflate) :-(